# Bundling Platform plugin folder with pyinstaller (--onefile)

Tags: python, qt, plugins, pyqt, pyinstaller

i found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/23335354?noredirect=1#comment35734484_23335354) useful and did my works like it. but i have a problem:

i work all this works and i create my exe file (in windows8 x64) and it works fine. but problem is that when i run my exe file in client system (or a clean VM - that just install vcredist_x64) it does not work and give me this error:

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin “windows”.

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

however, i checked QCoreApplication.libraryPaths() and i find that the qt5_plugins is in temp folder and program detect it ([u'C:\Users\Madoodia\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI175122\qt5_plugins'])

and i found that pyinstaller have qt5_plugins folder in temp, but not detect it in client system,even it can not detect that i set windows icon to window and don't show it.
the dll file related to icon file is "qt5_plugins/imageformats/qico.dll".

app.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.ico'))

i really appriciate for any help.